# Change in travel dates while waiting for Schengen Visa result

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas

I applied for a Germany Schengen visa and I'm waiting for the result. Assuming that I get the visa: In my application I stated the dates of travel **from December 15 to December 31, 2021** I also bought the health insurance plan for said dates. Let's say there's a change in plans, and I want to go from December 10th, 2021 rather than December 15th.

Question: is it legal to do so, or will there be there any record on my Schengen visa, stating that **I have to travel on the date that I used in my visa application** (December 15th - December 31st)?

Comment: It's likely that your visa will be limited to your planned travel dates.  Authorities are supposed to give the visa a period of validity that covers the travel dates in the application plus a few days of leeway at each end to accommodate changes in plans, but some do not do this.  I don't know what Germany's practice is.  You might therefore want to narrow this question a bit to ask specifically about Germany.

Comment: thanks my friend from my other question <3

Comment: For health insurance you should check the terms and conditions. You may not be covered 
 outside the specified dates (unless it is a one-year policy or similar), but there may be a way to change the period.

Answer (score 4):

I asked the German Consulate in Toronto and here is their answer (relevant excerpt from the full [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCuVp.jpg)):

> With regards to your question, a tourist visa will be issued as per submitted documents at your visa appointment. In other words, if you submit documents for a trip to Germany from December 23rd to 31st, the visa will be issued for exactly that time period. It is not possible to enter the country at an earlier date in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your mind or slightly altering your plans is not illegal *per se* and the visa sticker won't mention your original plan. On the other hand, your visa will have a period of validity and that's the only thing that matters. If, as is likely, you are issued a visa valid from December 15th then you are out of luck and cannot present yourself to the border five days earlier (if entering by plane, you would be denied boading). If for some reason your visa starts earlier or if you change your plans to travel later then it's perfectly fine.